# How to achieve complex header in Bootsfaces datatable

Tags: jsf, datatable, datatables, bootsfaces

I am using Bootsfaces datatable to display my data. However, I want to achieve complex header as shown here:  https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/complex_header.html

I tried to add `<th rowspan>` and `<th colspan>` directly under header facet in the first dataTableColumn, but that have a ugly empty row at the top.

I also tried to add the whole header facet under `<b:dataTable...>` tag, before the fist `<b:dataTableColumn>`, but that header code won't be generated into the html. Any other suggestions? I do not want to switch to primefaces or richfaces as my framework as been fixed.

My code that trying to achieve the complex header  looks like below:

```
<b:dataTable value="#{podStatusListBean.podStatusBeanList}" 
                      var="podStatus"
                      id="podStatuses">
     <b:dataTableColumn footer-style='background-color:orange'
                        footer-styleclass="{podStatusListBean.footerVisibility}">
               <f:facet name="header">
                    <tr>
                      <th rowspan="2">Name</th>
                      <th colspan="2">HR Information</th>
                      <th colspan="3">Contact</th>
                    </tr>
               </f:facet>
  ...
```

Comment: can anyone help?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/795.

Answer (score 0):

This is a new feature we've added to the next BootsFaces version (probably 1.2). As of June 15, 2017, the current version of BootsFaces 1.1.1 only supports complex headers on a per-column basis.

**Complex headers per column** (supported since BootsFaces 0.8.0):
Add a header facets to the `<b:dataTableColumn />`, pretty much the way you tried. But keep in mind that BootsFaces already generates the `<tr>` and `<th>` tags, so you can nest them a second time. But you can do something like this:

```
<b:dataTableColumn>
  <f:facet name="header">
    <ul
      style="margin-bottom: 0; list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0">
        <li>Price</li>
        <li>Engine Power</li>
      </ul>
    </f:facet>
         € #{car.price}
         <br />
         #{car.enginePowerKW} KW (#{car.enginePower} hp) 
       </b:dataTableColumn>
</b:dataTable>
```

**More complex headers (will be supported beginning with BootsFaces 1.2.0):**
Add a header facet to the surrounding `<b:dataTable />` tag. In this case you're responsible for defining the correct number of table headers. If you skip one, you'll be rewarded by a JavaScript error. In many cases it will even go by unnoticed, but the initialization of the datatable is incomplete, so you'd rather be careful.

```
<b:dataTable value="#{carPool.carPool}"
             var="car"
             page-length="5"
             page-length-menu="5,10,20">
  <f:facet name="header">
     <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">Car</th>
      <th colspan="2">Appearance</th>
      <th colspan="2">Technical Data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Power</th>
 </tr>
    </f:facet>
   <b:dataTableColumn>
       #{car.brand}  #{car.type}
  </b:dataTableColumn>
   <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.color}" />
   <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.year}"  order="asc" />
   <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.price}" />
   <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.enginePower}"/>
 </b:dataTable>
```